# React hooks - how to force useEffect to run when state changes to the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

So I'm building a drum-pad type of app, and almost everything is working, except this.

Edit: Put the whole thing on codesandbox, if anyone wants to have a look: codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-darwin-jc9b5?file=/src/App.js

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [text, setText] = useState("");
const [theSound] = useSound(drumBank[index].url)   

function playThis(num) {
  setIndex(num)
}

useEffect(()=>{
  if (index !== null) {
    setText(drumBank[index].id);
    theSound(index);
    console.log(index)
  }
}, [index])
```

When I press a button, the index changes to the value associated with the button and then the useEffect hook plays the sound from an array at that **index**. However, when I press the same button more than once, it only plays once, because useState doesn't re-render the app when the **index** is changed to the same value.

I want to be able to press the same button multiple times and get the app to re-render, and therefore useEffect to run every time I press the button. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: I found this custom hooks for key press may be that can help you [useKeyPress](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/)

Comment: Why use an `useEffect` hook at all for this and not just associate a keyPress event listener callback with a specific index value to pass to `theSound`? Perhaps I'm missing some context in this minimal example? The `useEffect` is intended to run an effect when a dependency changes, not when an asynchronous event happens. It doesn't seem to be the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @DrewReese is right, why use `useEffect` when it's not beneficial to you whatsoever. Just wrap all in one callback `playThis` is enough.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried that at first, putting everything within playThis(), but useSound is a custom hook that can not be inside a normal function. That's why I have it set to play the sound at **index** and not **num**. And if I put it in its current form within playThis, it lags behind and plays the sound at the previous index because state is asynchronous.

Comment: You don't need to put `useSound` in any callback, and for other than obvious hook reasons, but `theSound` can. I think a React ref may help you here. Do you have the ability to create a *running* codesandbox with this code mostly working? I have an idea but I am just not certain where the `text` state or `drumBank` come into play.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-darwin-jc9b5?file=/src/App.js

I put it all in codesandbox. Looks a little funky visually but all the code is there. I had some difficulty understanding the useSound hook in the first place, so your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I could come up with from your sandbox.

1. According to the docs each `useSound` is just a single sound, so when trying to update an index into a soundbank to use via React state the sound played will always be at least one render cycle delayed. I suggest creating a new custom hook to encapsulate your 9 drum sounds.

   `useDrumBank` consumes the drumbank array and instantiates the 9 drum sounds into an array.

   ```
   const useDrumBank = (drumbank) => {
     const [drum0] = useSound(drumbank[0].url);
     const [drum1] = useSound(drumbank[1].url);
     const [drum2] = useSound(drumbank[2].url);
     const [drum3] = useSound(drumbank[3].url);
     const [drum4] = useSound(drumbank[4].url);
     const [drum5] = useSound(drumbank[5].url);
     const [drum6] = useSound(drumbank[6].url);
     const [drum7] = useSound(drumbank[7].url);
     const [drum8] = useSound(drumbank[8].url);

     return [drum0, drum1, drum2, drum3, drum4, drum5, drum6, drum7, drum8];
   };
   ```
2. Update the component logic to pass the `drumBank` array to the new custom hook.

   ```
   const sounds = useDrumBank(drumBank);
   ```

Here's the full code:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", key);

    return () => document.removeEventListener("keypress", key);
  }, []);

  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const sounds = useDrumBank(drumBank);

  function playThis(index) {
    drumBank[index]?.id && setText(drumBank[index].id);
    sounds[index]();
  }

  function key(e) {
    const index = drumBank.findIndex((drum) => drum.keyTrigger === e.key);
    index !== -1 && playThis(index);
  }

  return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="drumpad-container">
      <div id="display" className="drumpad-display">
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-1" onClick={() => playThis(0)}>
        Q
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-2" onClick={() => playThis(1)}>
        W
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-3" onClick={() => playThis(2)}>
        E
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-4" onClick={() => playThis(3)}>
        A
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-5" onClick={() => playThis(4)}>
        S
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-6" onClick={() => playThis(5)}>
        D
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-7" onClick={() => playThis(6)}>
        Z
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-8" onClick={() => playThis(7)}>
        X
      </button>
      <button className="drum-pad" id="drum-pad-9" onClick={() => playThis(8)}>
        C
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-hooks-how-to-force-useeffect-to-run-when-state-changes-to-the-same-value]

## Usage Notes

[No sounds immediately after load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sound#no-sounds-immediately-after-load)

> For the user's sake, browsers don't allow websites to produce sound
> until the user has interacted with them (eg. by clicking on
> something). No sound will be produced until the user clicks, taps, or
> triggers something.

Getting the keypresses to consistently work seems to be an issue and I don't immediately have a solution in mind, but at least at this point the button clicks work and the sounds are played synchronously.

Comment: Thank you! I was tinkering by myself last evening and figured out a solution similar to that, but it's nice to know that I went the right way. That issue with the keypresses happened in my version of the app too, so it must again be something wrong with the useSound hook or its Howler dependency. I'll keep looking for a fix for that myself, if not, back to StackoverFlow with me.

Comment: @Lursmani Well, I linked a relevant note about the keypresses from the docs (seems related at least), but it seems a bit "random" when they work... like an edit in the codesandbox would make the keypresses work. This isn't something to rely on in the app though. It was fun to tinker with though, so thanks. If you felt like also giving a +1 for the help and information I wouldn't mind. Good luck, mate.

Comment: Will add +1 now. Just got 15 rep so I couldn't +1 before. And yeah I have the same issue, modifying even a single unrelated character in the code makes the sounds work. 

I tried adding a "power button" that only allows the sounds to play if the power is turned on, but the keys still don't work. So the investigation continues.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered combining those discrete state variables (value types) into a single reference type state object?

Instead of having an effect that sets the text when the index changes you just set the entire state at the same time.

As long as you ensure this is a new object/reference then the effect will fire. The effect is then only responsible for playing the sound based on the current state.

Here's some sample code

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ index: 0, text: '', }); 
const playThis = (num) => { 
    setState({ index: num, text: drumBank[num].id, }); 
}; 
useEffect(() => { 
    theSound(state.index); 
}, [state]);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, maybe with code samples? I am still new to js and react, so some of the terminology confuses me a little.

Comment: In terms of a very quick example, it'd look something like this:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
       index: 0,
       text: '',
    });

    const playThis = (num) => {
       setState({
          index: num,
          text: drumBank[num].id,
       });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
       theSound(state.index);
    }, [state]);

```

One of the commenters above makes a good point though - if playThis is just called in response to user input, you probably don't event need useEffect and can do everything in playThis.

Comment: Urgh, anyone know how to format code blocks on here?!

Comment: Ah yes, I tried that before actually. Problem is, theSound doesn't play the file passed to it as an argument, it only plays the file passed to useSound hook, which has to be outside the function. That's why I had to define index, so I could pass it to useSound, but then the index lagged behind.

Overall, I decided to just make every version of the useSound hook unique and then play the one I need instead of making a general hook, since I only have 9 sounds. I still want to know what the others had in mind, though, as I will learn from it.

Comment: Ah I see - in that case you could still pass the index from state to the useSound hook. It really depends on the implementation of that hook as to whether it will respond to state changes, but given that it was working with index then it should also work with state.index.

Comment: Unfortunately that caused the same lag. The index would be set to the previous value, not the current one. I could just stop using the useSound hook but then I'd have to make a function that plays sound on click and I think that my current implementation is good enough for now.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the way useSound (which I'm not familiar with) works.  I think if I were you I'd declare a useSound instance for each sound you want to play, and then just make the appropriate function call based on the selected item.  No effects needed.

Comment: Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/drum-pad-forked-49w26?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! This one works. I actually tinkered with it myself last evening and came up with a similar solution, but its nice to know that others had the same idea. Now I just gotta fix the issue with keypresses not playing the sound. Most likely issue with one of the dependencies.

Comment: No worries.  I didn't really look at the key function but if I were you I would ensure that the key function definition is prior to the definition of useEffect, i.e. where it's used.  You should also ensure that you tidy up the listener in the cleanup of the effect.

Comment: Like this, though it doesn't seem to work until you edit the code (even if you don't change anything). Could be a codesandbox issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/drum-pad-forked-49w26?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Not a codesanbox issue, it happens on my local build too. I have a similar build, just put on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/drum-pad-jc9b5?file=/src/drumPad.css

Haven't done cleanup yet, but the issue is still there regardless.