# Ionic-React - setState doesn't cause re-render

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

When I call `setMyState` within a `useEffect` hook, my understanding is react should re-run the logic to choose the component (either `MyPage` or `IonSpinner` in this case), but `MyPage` doesn't render unless I switch to a different tab and come back (using Ionic's IonTabs).

I confirmed `setMyState` is running because it updates other parts of the application (ex. triggers a different `useEffect`) and I know `MyPage` isn't being rendered because I'm doing a `console.log()` on the first line of rendering `MyPage` and this log doesn't appear.

Can someone help me with why this is happening?

```
<IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
        <IonTabs>
            <IonRouterOutlet>
                <Route exact path="/:tab(MyTab)">
                    {myState ? <MyPage /> : <IonSpinner />}
                </Route>
... more code ...
```

EDIT:

Pretty sure it's a bug in Ionic? After `useEffect` runs `setMyState`, react does a render like it's supposed to but then the `IonRouterOutlet` has no children (none displayed in React Dev Tools).

I traced this back to the `ReactRouterViewStack` calling `getChildrenToRender()` which creates `const viewItems`. This `viewItems` object is empty `{}` because the `viewStack` is empty `{}`. I don't know how the `viewStack` is meant to be populated so I'm not sure where to go from here, but I think `addViewItem` is not running?

When I go to another tab and then back to this tab, everything renders correctly and the children to `IonRouterOutlet` are shown in React Dev Tools.

Files:

`node_modules/@ionic/react/dist/index.esm.js`

`node_modules/@ionic/react-router/dist/index.esm.js`

Comment: Could you please provide more of your code? Currently using it like `<Route path="/home" render={() => authInfo?.loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Login />} exact />` working fine.

Answer (score -1):

try adding MyState in the Dependency array of useEffect

[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLt2o.png)

Comment: Hi Mian. I think calling setState within useEffect with the state as a dependency is going to cause an infinite loop, no?

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup). Having said that, I'm not sure I understand your need, can you (in your post) explain what data you have, and what you want your code to do, in order to get the data you need (where you show examples of both the data you have, and the data you need that to become).

Comment: @esafresa no, only if u change every time to a different value [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560406/react-hooks-how-to-force-useeffect-to-run-when-state-changes-to-the-same-value)

Comment: @csaar In my case, `myState` is an object, so React will see it as changed and re-render. I'll post some more code in a bit.